# How to use aggregate column in where clause when using group by

Tags: mysql, aggregate, where

I've following table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_fname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_lname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `released_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock_quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pages` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`)
)
```

Trying to find out the author's first and last book release year only for authors who have more than one book.
Following is the query

```sql
SELECT author_lname,
       MIN(released_year) first_release,
       MAX(released_year) last_release,
       COUNT(*) book_count,
       MAX(pages) max_page_count
FROM books
GROUP BY author_lname
ORDER BY book_count DESC;
```

But I can't use `book_count` in `where` clause so I can do `book_count > 1`
I'm looking for an explanation of why this is not possible & then how to get the expected result.

Comment: Check out the `having` clause.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! It might be an idea to head over to dbfiddle.uk and construct a fiddle - some sample data and desired result? I don't know why somebody voted to close this question. For me, it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why it is not possible

The `WHERE` clause applies conditions to filter rows one row at a time. The expression in the `WHERE` clause can make reference only to columns of a joined row. That is, any column from the multiple table(s) being joined, but not any aliases for columns formed by expressions in the select-list, and not any aliases for columns formed by aggregates over multiple rows.

Despite the `SELECT` clause appearing first in the query syntax, expressions of the select-list are evaluated *after* rows are filtered out by conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Likewise, aggregate expressions in the select-list are only applied to the subset of rows that pass the conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Therefore the `WHERE` clause must filter out rows first.

### How to achieve what you want

A couple of methods can solve this.

One is to use a derived table subquery. The outer query can apply conditions in its `WHERE` clause to filter out rows that are produced by the subquery, after the subquery does its aggregation and aliases and so on.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT author_lname,
       MIN(released_year) first_release,
       MAX(released_year) last_release,
       COUNT(*) book_count,
       MAX(pages) max_page_count
    FROM books
    GROUP BY author_lname
) AS derived
WHERE derived.book_count > 1
ORDER BY book_count DESC;
```

It should make no difference to ORDER BY inside a subquery, unless the subquery also uses LIMIT.

Another method is to use `HAVING` which is like `WHERE` in that it filters rows, but it functions after the aggregation is done, and select-list expressions have been evaluated. Think of `HAVING` as filtering *groups*, whereas `WHERE` filters individual *rows*.

```
SELECT author_lname,
       MIN(released_year) first_release,
       MAX(released_year) last_release,
       COUNT(*) book_count,
       MAX(pages) max_page_count
FROM books
GROUP BY author_lname
HAVING book_count > 1
ORDER BY book_count DESC;
```

### Which method is better?

I prefer to use `HAVING` where possible, because the derived table may have to create a temporary table to hold results, and temp tables can be a performance drag.

But there can be cases where using a derived-table subquery is necessary anyway. Perhaps you want to join the result of the subquery to another table, for example.

Comment: In most DBMSs you would need `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` you can't just use the alias.

Comment: @Charlieface, Yes, but the OP tagged their question [tag:mysql] and MySQL permits aliases to be used in the `HAVING` clause.